# Tkinter button if statements

Tags: python, tkinter

Can you use an if statement within the lambda:command part of a button declaration, examaple:
 `HalondrusButton = Button(mainFrame,text="Halondrus",command= lambda:[mainFrame.pack_forget(), raise_frame(bossFrame),currentBoss.set("Halondrus"),if GuildMasterPresent=="yes":changeRosterButton.pack()])`

I want to only show a specific item on the frame if the variable is equal to a certain value

Comment: You are *way* past what can reasonably be fitted into a `lambda`.  Write the code as a normal `def` function, pass that as the `command=` option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a function or a lambda command in a tkinter button. If you want to use an if statement in a lambda command, you must define a function that implements the lambda command with the if statement and then replace the lambda command with the function in your tkinter button.

See this tutorial for a simple example: [Tkinter Tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-button/)